# Is there a way to bind TAB to a control?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

I have been using TAB for walking backward in FPS games since the mid-90's.  I have never come across a game that will not let me bind to TAB except for Bioshock Infinite.  Is there a way to bind a command to that key?  Reconfiguring the key layout that I've been using for around 17 years is simply not acceptable just for this one game.

**Edit:**  The UserKeyMappings line in XuserOptions.ini is apparently base64 encoded.  I believe that if I can just decode it, edit it, and encode it back that I might be able to get this to work.  I've tried several online decoders, but they don't seem to decode the entire string.  Here's mine if anyone wants to try:

http://pastebin.com/USgfQn6m

```
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
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a program that could switch keyboard keys around for you.

Comment: @kotekzot I've tried AutoHotkey, but it doesn't work in the game.  Other key mappers force you to edit the registry which makes you have to reboot or log out and back in.

Comment: Paste the base64 string into this converter:
http://home.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/
Then copy the decoded hex bytes and paste them into your favourite hex editor (I used http://www.catch22.net/software/hexedit to "Paste special" in "single hex bytes" mode). Looks like someone already got started but is at an early stage of the analysis here: http://pastebin.com/MSubhSej

Otherwise, I'd try to use a keyboard remapper to work around the issue.

Comment: It seems the the code is invalid because of it's length. Are you sure that is the whole file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a way to bind this through the game directly. However there are [several](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/) [available](http://lifehacker.com/5883003/the-best-key-remapper-for-windows) [keymapping](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/remap-keyboard-free-tools-windows/) [utilities.](https://www.google.com/search?q=keyboard+mapping&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=#q=keyboard+mapping+utility+windows&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address)

I personally use one to have my caps lock and backspace keys switched (significantly more convenient), and it should allow you to switch your tab key with another bind-able key that you would use for the menu.

Comment: I can personally recommend sharpkeys. I used to do the remapping myself in the registry, but got tired of having to look up the right codes every time I reinstalled my computer. Sharpkeys makes my life a lot easier (I want my capslock key to be a second left ctrl and my insert dead)